# How to set the tooltip of a contentpresenter to the value it is showing?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

We have a `ListBox` with a custom `ListBoxItemTemplate` that shows some information using the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the `ListBox`.

The `ListBoxItemTemplate` has inside a `ContentPresenter`.

All we need to do is to set the Tooltip property of the `ContentPresenter` to show the same thing as the `ContentPresenter`.

I've tried to do this:

```
<ContenPresenter Tooltip={Path Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}/>
```

But I get the context without the `DisplayMemberPath` logic (the whole datacontext object).

How can I get the value shown by the ContentPresenter with the 'DisplayMemberPath' applied?

### Edit

Here the style without the **Tooltip** (the control has set this style and the `DisplayMemberPath` property with a Binding):

```
<Style x:Key="CheckListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckListBoxItemStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="177"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CheckListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">

        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Tag="CheckBox1">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </CheckBox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use both DisplayMemberPath property and ItemTemplate for listbox simultaneously. Could you please show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the value shown by the ContentPresenter with the 'DisplayMemberPath' applied?

You can't do this dynamically in pure XAML. If you know the value of the DisplayMemberPath property you can could bind to this property directly:

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Tag="CheckBox1"
                                                          ToolTip="{Binding Path=Content.Name, ElementName=cp}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="cp" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
</CheckBox>
```

But you cannot do something like `ToolTip="{Binding Path=Content.[DisplayMemberPath], ElementName=cp}"`.

You will have to write some code to achieve this. You could for example use a converter:

```
public class ContentConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string path = values[0] as string;
        object dataObject = values[1];

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && dataObject != null)
            return dataObject.GetType().GetProperty(path).GetValue(dataObject).ToString();

        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb11" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:ContentConverter x:Key="conv" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple" />
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Tag="CheckBox1">
                                            <CheckBox.ToolTip>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                                                    <Binding Path="DisplayMemberPath" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Content" ElementName="cp"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </CheckBox.ToolTip>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="cp" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="177"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I see your point. I will try to create an attached property as I don't like using converters with datacontext objects (content) as then looks like you're doing something more that visual conversion. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I am using reflection to get the value of the property with the dynamic name from the data object. You won't be able to avoid this if you want to use the *string* value of the DisplayMemberPath to get the actual value.

Comment: No, that's fine. It is more a separation of concerns issue. My point is that a Converter should have only visualization logic and passing a Datacontext object to the Converter then it is doing VM logic.

Comment: That's fair enough but my main point here is that you can't do this in the XAML markup of the template itself. Whether you are using a converter or an attached property to get the content of the tooltip is entirely up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined `ContentPresenter` inside Template,You cannot access Content in Binding. As per `DataContext` distribution, you're already in Content level.so it didnt worked, i guess changing `ContentPresenter` to `ContentControl` and `ToolTip` like below will work

```
<ContentControl Tooltip={Binding}/>
```

Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Adding a ContentControl inside a ControlTemplate its not working. The text nor the toolip are diplayed :\